# Popover is not dismissing itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, popover

I'm trying to get a `popover` to dismiss itself when I click a button, but it doesn't seem to be working. I know there are a few questions regarding this, but I think my set up is slightly different. In storyboards I have the following setup:

**View Controller -> (segue popover) -> View Controller 2**

View Controller 2 has a "Done" button linked to an IBAction as follows:

```
- (IBAction)returnCommand:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I know that you can click outside of the popup to dismiss it, but I want to do a few other things when **Done** is pressed. With this code, nothing happens when I click the "done" button.

Comment: You need to send a message to View Controller 1 that the operations are done. View Controller 1 should then dismiss the popover.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIPopover method `dismissPopoverAnimated:` to dismiss the popover. From the docs:

> **Discussion**
>
> You can use this method to dismiss the popover programmatically in
>   response to taps inside the popover window. Taps outside of the
>   popover’s contents automatically dismiss the popover.

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample code:

```
- (IBAction)returnCommand:(id)sender {
     if ([viewController2 isPopoverVisible]) {
         [viewController2 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         viewController2 = nil;
         return;
     }
}
```